# Explain how a digital signature is employed for providing a proof of authenticity (not integrity!) of a file

Tags: digital-signature

Explain how a digital signature is employed for providing a proof of authenticity (not integrity!) of a file.

Comment: For clarification
This is not a homework but to increase personal knowledge

Comment: It is still too broad and shows not even an attempt of your own research, similar to your previous question. And given the tags you've set (i.e. malware and security-theater) it looks like that you not even understand the basics of what you are asking about, i.e. what a digital signature is, what authenticity and what integrity mean.

Comment: Can you prove authenticity if you can't prove integrity?

Comment: I have differed with Dr. in this question, but Dr. is determined to find the answer to the same question

Comment: @azizalhaj who is Dr.? You keep saying the Dr asked you these questions.

Comment: We expect that you have done at least a little research before asking here. When I google "digital signature authenticity" I get a large number of hits explaining these concepts. Please make sure that you have taken some steps of your own to answer these questions.

Comment: @schroeder  Do you like fruit?

Comment: @azizalhaj I do not understand your question about "fruit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A digital signature is generated with a private key and can be validated by anybody who has the public key.
So, the digital signature of an object (e.g. a file) ensures that the one who generated the signature (the signer) is the one having the private key. This is called "signer authenticity".
As the signature is tied to the content (i.e. a different object would have a different signature), it also verifies that the object (e.g. the file) has not been modified in its way to the receiver.